# for range on slice on array yields [T] instead of T?

Tags: rust

I wand to iterate on part of a slice knowing how many items of that slice i want to iterate on.
How can I achieve that?

What i've tried is to have a `for of` on a range `[0..only]` but indexing my slice with the produced index gives me a `[T]` instead of a `T`. How come? what i am missing?

```rust
fn in_slice(slice: &[u8], only: usize) {
    for index in [0..only] {
        println!("{}", slice[index]); // slice[index] here is a [u8] and not a u8
    }
}

fn main() {
    in_slice(&[1, 2, 3], 2)
}
```

Comment: The `[]` syntax is extra.  You are wrapping your `Range<usize>` in an array by doing that.  -> `for index in 0..only {`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`0..only` is a `Range<usize>`. `[0..only]` is a `[Range<usize>; 1]`, i.e. an array with an element type `Range<usize>` and length `1`.

Therefore, iterating over `[0..only]` will yield a single element of type `Range<usize>`.

To iterate over the range and yield `usize`s, use the range:

```rust
 for index in 0..only {
    println!("{}", slice[index]);
 }
```

Comment: It should be noted, that while this is true, it's an anti-pattern in Rust vs the much more idiomatic `for x in slice { ...`.

Comment: In this situation that would be `for x in slice[..only] { ...`

Comment: @isaactfa yep but sometimes you need to wolk with the indexes

Comment: @zedryas: To get the indices the idiomatic way would be `for (idx, x) in slice[..only].iter().enumerate() { ...`. Unless you need to somehow limit the borrrowing of the `x` value itself.